# Como criar uma estrutura de services no vuejs usando typescript e generics?

Tags: typescript, genéricos, axios

Normalmente quando crio um projeto Vuejs + Typescript gosto de dividir os Services criando os métodos que realizam requests de post, update, get e delete mas percebi que estava repetindo muito código criando muitos services com código repetido mudando somente a rota e achei que seria interessante usar generics criando uma classe com os métodos prontos e nas classes específicas usar o extends dos métodos. Vocês conhecem alguma forma ou podem me dar dicas de como fazer isso?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.